# When I use delegate to pass value to another ViewController,I find the delegate does nothing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates

When I use delegate to pass value to another `ViewController`,I find the delegate does nothing. 
I just can delete the delegate and still I can pass the value!

When i need to pass a value from `ViewControllerA` to `ViewControllerB`, i just did this which does work!

```
- (IBAction)sendToB:(id)sender {
ViewControllerB *viewB=[[ViewControllerB alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
[viewB getValue:self.textInput.text];
[self presentViewController:viewB animated:YES completion:nil];  }
```

then in `ViewControllerB`, i do get the value.
But this is nothing to do with delegate and i remember people all say using delegate to pass value between two `ViewControllers`. So what is the difference?Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass values in many ways, one you showed is also used to pass values.

But suppose a case occurs that you have to update value to `ViewControllerA` from your presented `ViewControllerB` then I am sure you will not be **initializing** `ViewControllerA` again and then try to pass the value.

In this case you will be needing `delegate` to do so and you can achieve this by using `protocol` in the following way:-

In `ViewControllerB.h` file create your protocol

```
@protocol sampleDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)updatedValue:(NSString* )newData;
@end

@property (nonatomic,assign)id<delegate>delegateObj;
```

In `ViewControllerB.m` file

```
- (IBAction)sendToA:(id)sender 
{
   [self.delegateObj updatedValue:@"Updated value"];
}
```

Now in `ViewControllerA.m` file override your `ViewControllerB's` delegate object:

```
- (IBAction)sendToB:(id)sender
{
    ViewControllerB *viewB=[[ViewControllerB alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
    [viewB setDelegate:self];
    [viewB getValue:self.textInput.text];
    [self presentViewController:viewB animated:YES completion:nil];
}



//Implement the protocol method here in ViewControllerA.m

- (void)updatedValue:(NSString* )newData
{
   NSLog(@"Value that updated in ViewControllerB is %@",newData);
}
```

Hope this helps you to understand the importance of Delegates. :)

Comment: I was wondering when i try to move back to VCA from VCB, don't i need to use: ViewControllerA *viewA=[ViewControllerA alloc]init]; [self presentViewController:viewA animated:YES completion:nil]; ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a delegate would be one way of getting a value back from VCB to VCA.  In that case, VCA would implement a delegate protocol (usually) and pass itself to VCB as a delegate.  VCB would then call something like `[delegate update:value]` when it had the new value.

Comment: So, you mean we just don't need delegate way when we are only  doing passing a value from VCA to VCB? For example, there is a textField of VCA in which i input something and then i press the button to send the text in textField to VCB in which the passed value is displayed within a label.

Comment: Right because, as you've seen, VCA will already have a reference to VCB either because it creates it explicitly or because of a segue.  Unless you do something special, though, VCB usually won't know what caused it to appear.  (So, delegates or notifications or a standalone data model.)

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to imply you think you must use delegates in every situation when one VC wants to pass data to another. This is not the case, delegates are only used if its necessary and/or applicable and is not the only way.

In your example if you wanted to pass a value from VCB back to VCA would be an example of where a delegate could be used.
You would use the delegate when VCB does not know what object created it but it know it has some value to pass back to whatever that object was. That way VBC could be created by objects of different types and VCB can always pass the value back to them without knowing anything about them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think i'm becoming a little clearer about that but not completely.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates is used to pass values backwards. When data passed forwards, then commonly used yours construction.